# detect gulp task in php blade of laravel

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm, webpack

I have this in multiple entires in my blade template

```
@if (!App::environment('production'))
<script src="/bundle/feed.chunk.js"></script>
@else
<script src="{{ elixir('feed.chunk.js') }}"></script>
@endif
```

where App:enviroment is get from .env file. I want to add another condition. Like if hot reload is true go to another condition. Can I catch gulp's task name?